# Get Username From WinXP Start Menu

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have tried using  `System.Environment.UserName` and `My.User.Name` in VB.
But I get the result:  **ASIA/rz2kl1** (which is my username)

But I want (Doe, John) which is the name associated with username and comes on top of the start menu.

Comment: Why is this tagged F#? It appears to be a vb.net or general .net question rather than one which is F# specific.

Comment: `userName = "(Doe, John)"` No seriously with out telling us why you expect `(Doe, John)` and not the user name is going to be hard to give you anything helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetUserNameEx` function.

> Retrieves the name of the user or other security principal associated with the calling thread. You can specify the format of the returned name.
>
> If the thread is impersonating a client, GetUserNameEx returns the name of the client.

More documentation can be found [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724435%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be helpful:

```
    Dim UserName As String = "ASIA\rz2kl1 (Doe, John)"
    Dim ExtractName() As String = UserName.Split()
    Dim Name As String = ExtractName(1) + " " + ExtractName(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following reference
[image: Account Management Reference]

---

Add the following import:

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

---

Finally, add the following line of code:

```
Dim userFullName As String = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName
```